# How do I view replays for attacks?

Tags: clash-of-clans-builder-base

In the normal base on Clash of Clans, there is an envelope you can click on to get to your attack and defense logs, however the builder base doesn't have one. Where are my replays located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While at the Battle Base, simply click the Attack button and there will be a Battle Log button in the bottom right corner. In the battle log you will be able to view replays of both your recent attacks and defenses.